# object from multidimensional array based on ID not being removed - Angular 4/ Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a data structure. It goes as follows --

```
[{
   propertyoutsideid: 1,
   items: [
        {itemId: 1, something: 'something'}.
        {itemId: 2, something: 'something'}.
        {itemId: 3, something: 'something'}.
]
},{
   propertyoutsideid: 2,
   items: [
        {itemId: 4, something: 'something'}.
        {itemId: 5, something: 'something'}.
        {itemId: 6, something: 'something'}.
 ]
}
]
```

I'm asking a basic filter question but unsure how to go about it because of how this structure is layered. I'm trying to remove the item based on the id.

Component.ts

```
retrieveidfunction(objectwithid){
this.allItems = this.allItems.forEach(res3 => {
   return res3.items.filter(res4 => {
      return res4.itemId != objectwithid.itemId
     }
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return res4.itemId != this.objectwithid.itemId` to

`return res4.itemId != objectwithid.itemId`.

```js
let allItems=[{
   propertyoutsideid: 1,
   items: [
        {itemId: 1, something: 'something'},
        {itemId: 2, something: 'something'},
        {itemId: 3, something: 'something'}
]},{
   propertyoutsideid: 2,
   items: [
        {itemId: 4, something: 'something'},
        {itemId: 5, something: 'something'},
        {itemId: 6, something: 'something'}
 ]}]

function retrieveidfunction(objectwithid){
  allItems.forEach((res3,i) => {
   allItems[i] = res3.items.filter(res4 => {
      return res4.itemId != objectwithid.itemId
   });
  });
}
let objectwithid = {itemId: 4}
retrieveidfunction(objectwithid)

console.log(allItems);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had that in my code, didn't properly copy and paste.

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm, please follow the updated snippet.

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm, I have update my answer. Please have a look.....thanks.